# Background strange color in Chrome browser but not in Edge

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to React and cant figure out why my App look different on Chrome and Edge Browser. It show stripes in between images and try to remove them.
The strange thing is when I debug in VCode it looks fine and debug browser is Chrome
This is the [App web site under construction](http://greta.portplays.com/)

This is Edge Browser and image does not show the stripes in between images:

[image]

This is Chrome and stripes is there:

[image]

And here is the css:
At row 75 I removed the stripe background color like this:
`/* background-color: #1d1d1e; this is background that show in between slides*/`

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.is-180x180 {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
}
.skill-list > li {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
.has-bg-image {
  background-image: url("../images/GretaThunberg collage2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.bulma-image {
  width: 200px;
}
.interests {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.summary-text {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 36em;
}
.skill-percentage {
  float: right;
}

/* For the under construction text on images */
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

/* //General */
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1d1d1e;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

* {
  outline: none;
}

/* //Timeline carousel for weeks */

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1d1d1e;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

* {
  outline: none;
}

.timeline-carousel {
  padding: 86px 6.9444% 90px 6.9444%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.timeline-carousel:after,
.timeline-carousel:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6.9444%;
   /* background-color: #1d1d1e; this is background that show in between slides*/ 
  z-index: 3;
}

.timeline-carousel:after {
  left: 0;
}

.timeline-carousel:before {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.timeline-carousel .slick-list {
  overflow: visible;
}

.timeline-carousel .slick-dots {
  bottom: -73px;
}

.timeline-carousel h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 46px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.timeline-carousel__image {
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 164px;
}

.timeline-carousel__item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.timeline-carousel__item .media-wrapper {
  opacity: 0.4;
  padding-bottom: 71.4%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
}

.timeline-carousel__item:last-child .timeline-carousel__item-inner:after {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 45px;
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner .year {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: white;
  display: table;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #1d1d1e;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin: -15px 0 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner .year:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #1d1d1e;
  z-index: 3;
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner .month {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b38c52;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: white;
  width: 60%;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner .read-more {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #b38c52;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner .read-more:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b38c52;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner .read-more:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner .pointer {
  height: 29px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: -4px 0 16px;
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner .pointer:after,
.timeline-carousel__item-inner .pointer:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner .pointer:after {
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #b38c52;
}

.timeline-carousel__item-inner .pointer:before {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 4px;
  background-color: #b38c52;
}

.timeline-carousel .slick-active .media-wrapper {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.slick-dots {
  bottom: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slick-dots li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 6px;
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.slick-dots li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background: #b38c52;
  border-color: #b38c52;
}

.slick-dots li button {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
}

.slick-dots li button:hover {
  background: #b38c52;
  border-color: #b38c52;
}

.link {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.link a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.link .fa {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Can you uncomment those stripes on your website? I added background-color to `.timeline-carousel:before` and I can see them on Edge

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear I dont want stripes what Edge show is good

Comment: I cant see them on Chrome needed, you commented `background-color` out, just remove that line. Or do you want to remove the whole element?

Comment: You can always add: `background-color: transparent` by the way

Comment: Strange why do I see them on Chrome and not you

Comment: Try clearing your cache perhaps?

Comment: If you go here http://greta.portplays.com/ dont you see the stripes you mean? That's strange I tried on 3 different chrome accounts

Comment: Nope, I cant see it. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/iFONjbq.png

Comment: Thanks I Hold down Ctrl and press F5.in the chrome browser and it bypass cache so now I dont see strips